# Getting exception in a jquery file while running my web application in internet explorer although its running in google chrome browser

Tags: html, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

This script i have used to display and hide the text box. I'm getting exception while running my application in internet explorer although its running fine in Google chrome. Any help will greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {


        $("#textbox2").hide();
        $("#reasonforseparation").change(function () {
            debugger
            if ($(this).val() == 7) {
                $("#textbox2").show();

            }
            else {
                $("#textbox2").hide();


            }
        });
    })

</script>
```

This is a dynamic file

```
 {
var _alreadyRunned = false;
setTimeout(function _watcherReady() {
    if (window.document.readyState === "complete" && !_alreadyRunned) {
        avastBHO.SERPWatcherOnReadyState();// at this line exception occured
        _alreadyRunned = true;
    } else {
        timer = setTimeout(_watcherReady, 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
};
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Have you found which line is causing the error? What's `debugger` by the way?

Comment: The exception is in dynamic jquery file

Comment: now check the code i've added a dynamic jquery file in which the exception is occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed Avast antivirus, and the Browser Plugin causes problems.

Try to close the Avast PlugIn in Internet Explorer > Manage Add-On and disable Avast Online Security

Good luck!!!

Comment: Just wondering if you know how one as a developer might accommodate this Avast thing? I am having issues with it in a jQuery mobile site aswell and was wondering if there is anything I can do my end so my users get a working site even if they do have the AVAST plugin installed (since it installs by default with Avast and millions of people use that...)

Comment: Could try redefine _watcherReady, avastBHO, or avastBHO.SERPWatcherOnReadyState()